# How can I adjust the position of the signature to be more dynamic (laravel dompdf)?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5.3, dompdf

My controller is like this :

```
public function listdata(Request $request)
{
    ...
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('test_print.test', ['data' => $data]);
    $pdf->setPaper('legal', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('test_print.test');
}
```

My pdf view is like this :

```
<h1>This is test</h1>

<table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-3wr7">kolom 1</th>
        <th class="tg-3wr7">kolom 2</th>
        <th class="tg-3wr7">kolom 3</th>
        <th class="tg-3wr7">kolom 4</th>
        <th class="tg-3wr7">kolom 5</th>
    </tr>
    @php ($row = 22)
    @for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++)
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-rv4w">test 1</td>
        <td class="tg-rv4w">test 1</td>
        <td class="tg-rv4w">test 1</td>
        <td class="tg-rv4w">test 1</td>
        <td class="tg-rv4w">test 1</td>
    </tr>
    @endfor
</table>

<br>
<!-- start position signature -->
<div class="signature">
    London,&nbsp;8 January 2017<br>
    Chelsea Player<br><br><br><br>
    Eden Hazard<br>
</div>
 <!-- end position signature -->
```

The result is like this : 
[image]

It looks content of a signature separate to 2. There are at page 1 and there are at page 2

I want to make the results look like this :
[image]

how I do it?

Answer (score 0):

From [DOMPDF docs](https://jonathanstark.com/labs/dompdf/www/faq.php#page_break):

> Page breaks can be inserted by applying the CSS properties [`page-break-before`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#propdef-page-break-before) and [`page-break-after`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#propdef-page-break-after) to any block level element.

So insert class with defined property and use this class. For testing you could just insert something like this instead of `<br>`:

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
```

Comment: My data is dynamic. If I change my data. `$row = 10`. It looks like this : http://postimg.org/image/8x25gthqf/. Should position the signature on page 1

Comment: If what you're saying is that you want this to only appear on the next page try styling your "signature" class with `page-break-inside: avoid;`